# Why does mobile specific css only seem to target screen size?

Tags: android, ios, css, iphone, mobile

I am relatively new to responsive web development and I've been confused on media queries for a while.

How does this:

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 320px) {}
```

Become iPhone specific when it only targets screen size? Wouldn't many more devices become targeted by this?

I see references like this: http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/ and wonder why this is the standard.

And is there truly a way to target *iPhone only* versus *Android only*?

Much thanks.

Comment: Using media query you can only target screen size not os. for targeting os you should use JS.

Answer (score 0):

A media query will work on all devices. This only detects the width of a screen and nothing more.

The site you were viewing was just showing specific sizes for multiple devices. An iPad screen may not be the same width as say a Android Tablet screen.